# java xml formatting issue

Tags: java, xml

I am having an issue with *java org.w3c.dom.Document*. I had to remove the *standalone* property from prolog and now the formatting between proglog and body is gone (the new line?)

Previous code:

```
 Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
```

Previous output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<response>
    <params>
        <form>
            ...
        </form>
    </params>
</response>
```

Current code:

```
 Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
 document.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><response>
    <params>
        <form>
            ...
        </form>
    </params>
</response>
```

Other relevant code section:

```
private Transformer getTransformer() {
    Transformer transformer = null;

    try {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.MEDIA_TYPE, "string");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return transformer;
}
```

Did anyone came across this issue?